# c code text not displayed

Tags: c, printf

iv'e written a part of a code which basically transfers text from a txt file into a variable and prints it(as a part of a program),yet it does not print the contents at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WRONG_ARGUMENTS     (-1)

int Lines(FILE * file);
int Length(FILE * file);
int Read(FILE * file);
int Lines(FILE * file)
                {
                    int c=0,count=0;
                    ++count;
                    while(c!=EOF)
                    {
                        c=fgetc(file);
                        if(c=='\n')
                            ++count;
                    }
                    return count;
                }
                int Length(FILE * file)
                {
                    int c,count=0;
                    while((c=fgetc(file))!=EOF)
                    {
                        ++count;
                    }
                    return count;
                }

         int Reader(FILE * Text,char * File)
         {
             int counter=0;
             while(fscanf(Text,"%s",File)!=EOF)
             {
                 ++counter;
                 strcat(File," ");
             }
             return counter;
         }
int main(int argc,char * argv[]) {
    FILE * Text=NULL;


    if(argc!=2)
    {
        printf("usage:library text dictionary\n");
        return -1;
    }
    Text = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(Text==NULL)
    {
        printf("file %s could not be opened\n",argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

        char * File = "";
         File=malloc(Length(Text)*(sizeof(char)));

int r = Reader(Text,File);
printf(File);

return 0;
}
```

i will be more than glad to understand the problem in the partial code 
the output is x>

thanks,

Comment: `int c,count=0;` c is uninitialised. `while(c!=EOF)`{}` Anything can happen here. BTW: after the first scan, the file is still positioned at it's EOF. extra: `File=malloc(Length(Text)*(sizeof(char)));` File is unitialised, the srecat() later will probably not like this fact.

Comment: can you please reffer to the file being positioned at its EOF?where does it occure,and how do i reset it?

Comment: You've pasted all of your functions in the middle of your main function. Can you post your code properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following cut-down example. You'll notice that the `getFileLength` function (a) doesn't actually read anything from the file and (b) makes use of the `fseek` and `ftell` functions - fseek is the function that you use to reposition the file-pointer when it reaches EOF.

Imagine that you weren't printing the data, but doing something else with it. What if the file is a billion bytes long? We sure don't want to read 1,000,000,000 times from it just to determine its length!

As for the use of calloc - it zero initializes the data it allocates. Since you're reading text, you want to ensure that the text is NULL-terminated. (NULL generally = 0, though I've seen evil macros that change this) This NULL terminator is also why I allocate 1 byte more than the file contains.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long getFileLength(FILE *input)
{
    long result;
    long origPos = ftell(input);
    fseek(input, 0, SEEK_END);
    result = ftell(input);
    fseek(input, origPos, SEEK_SET);
    return result;
}

int main (void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    long fileLen, numBytesRead;
    char *data;

    fp = fopen("main.cpp", "rb");
    fileLen = getFileLength(fp);
    data = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char), fileLen+1);
    numBytesRead = fread(data, sizeof(char), fileLen, fp);
    if (numBytesRead != fileLen)
        printf("Error reading all bytes from file. Expected: %d, Read %d\n", fileLen, numBytesRead);
    else
        printf("%s", data);
    free(data);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much,but i would really like to fix my existing code as i am truely trying to learn from it .how can i fix my code to function as intended?

Comment: thanks,i ended up using your solution.for the reading,i tried using my method but it only prints the last word.any thoughts?

Comment: You're welcome. As someone else said - you're leaving the file-pointer at the end of the file. In each of `Lines`, `Length` and `Read` you read until you hit EOF - but nowhere in the program do you reset the file-pointer back to byte 0 of the file. I've manipuated the pointer in getFileLength. You just need to use SEEK_SET with a value of 0 - have a look at the help for that function, for a better description than I can give you now, at 4.30am :)

Comment: @user3005945 - nope, can't see any other issues, though I'm a little past my 'best-before' time for today. :grin:

Comment: thanks :D.i tried checking the matter by adding a counter inside Read.it actually does return the number of words in my string,but it still only prints the last word :(

Comment: Ahhhh! Have a look at `Reader` - you keep overwriting the start of the memory buffer you have. You can use fgets to read each line into a temporary buffer, before using strcat to append that text onto the end of your main buffer. fgets has all kinds of pitfalls. At this stage for you, I'll recommend using a buffer of (say) 2048 or 4096 bytes. **Note** This is a quick hack. Please read some more on how to use fgets safely (as in, to avoid buffer overflow) OR, use a similarly large buffer with fscanf. Then as well as `strcat`ing a space after each read, strcat the contents of the temporary bufr.

Comment: i appologize for the ingnorance,but how do i overwrite the start?doesnt fscanf(Text,"%s",File) simply append?if not,how can i read 1 word each time?i would truely love avoiding a hack of using a buffer.

Comment: No problem. Nope, fscanf copies the read data into the start of the buffer. Cant think of any way around this when using C. If you look at the help for fgets, you can see that it reads until any of the following are satisfied **(a)** end-of-file is reached, or when **(b)** a newline character is read, or when **(c)** n-1 characters have been read, whichever comes first. Since the newline char is copied, you check to see if `buffer[ strlen(buffer) - 1]` contains '\n' - if so, you read the whole line. If not, the buffer was smaller than the line and you need to read again for more of the line.

Comment: okay.i unwilingly created a buffer,but now i receive an odd looking outcome:0>hello my name is eitan,while "0>" is not included in my text.

Comment: Can't think what it could be right now. Its 5.30am - I'm going to bed. If the text `0>` is contained in a previous (longer) line of text, consider clearing the buffer after you've copied its contents and before your read into it again. I'll look again this afternoon. :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm missing something. Your question is perfectly clear - it's my understanding of the C (file)text handling that's not up to par. I always seemed to get tripped-up by something. You probably noticed (a) I explicitly opened the file in binary mode (to avoid line-ending conversions) and (b) I read the whole file at once - with the exact number of bytes to read specified. Since you have to hold the whole file in memory anyway, I would, without seeing the assignment hand-out, just read the whole thing into a buffer, and then examine that buffer to count both words and lines. Sorry, g'luck.